# Events registration via webform + strict accommodation options

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I have created 1 event and using a webform to register people. The user can register multiple people using conditions shows/hides contact fields. I would like to include camping options with conditions.

•   A large tent which has to house 4 people
•   Single tents

Camping space is limited. If the user selects 7 people to register, I want them to be able to choose either:

1x large tent
3x single tents
Or 
7x single tents

If a user registers 3 people then a large tent is not an option, and so on.

Not sure if this is actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

via Conditionals you should be able to Hide - Large Tent if number of people is less than 4

Comment: There might be upward of 16 people being registered. Which complicates things as 4 large tents might be selected. If 1 person has a large tent then I would want make sure 3 other people have also selected large tent - which is possible, with a lot of conditions.

Comment: you could maybe use formula to calculate number of 'tent spaces/beds' and compare that to number of people and if it doesn't match tell them off